# comparing a string variable to an explicit char* value

Tags: c++, string, char

I don't understand why this code compiles and runs:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
// if (s == "done") {     // version 1
if ("done" == s) {        // version 2
    std::cout << "We're done here" << std::endl;
}
```

Version 1 works as I would expect.  The compiler sees that `s` is a `std::string`, and uses the `std::string` definition of `==` to do the comparison.

However, when comparing a variable to an explicit value, I like to use the trick of putting the explicit value first in case one day I accidentally use `=` instead and do an assignment instead.  Hence, version 2.

Now version 2 works on my compiler (llvm on MacOS) the same way as version 1, but I'm not sure why (or if it's a reliable result).  I would have though that the compiler sees "done" as a `char*` explicit value (literal) and says, "hey, `==` makes no sense on char*" and give me a compilation error message.  But my compiler doesn't do that, it compiles without complaint and the code executes the same way as version 1.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Do you know about `operator==` and [how it works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)?

Comment: If you enable warnings, the compiler will warn you if you do `if (x = 1)` when you intended to do `if (x == 1)`.  No need to contort the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `"done"` is not `char*`. It is `const char[5]`.

But in any case, it works because if you include `<string>`, which you must have to use `std::string`, then (before C++20) you include an overload for `operator==` of the form

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs,
                 const CharT* rhs );
```

and one of the form

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const CharT* lhs,
                 const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp for reference.

`std::string` is just `std::basic_string` with `CharT` being `char` and `Traits` and `Alloc` being some defaults that don't matter here.

So effectively one overload accepts a `const std::string&` as left-hand argument and `const char*` as right-hand argument, and the other accepts the reverse.

`const char[N]` can be deduced as `const char*` and it is implicitly convertible to the latter for every `N`, so the first overload is viable for `s == "done"` and the second for `"done" == s`.

The standard library is written with these overloads specifically so that your use will work. Your approach of using the `"done" == s` variant makes sense, because `"done" = s` would indeed be an error. `operator=` can only be overloaded with a class type on the left-hand side.

Since C++20, the overloads look a bit different. In particular it isn't necessary to have both anymore. The compiler now automatically tries overloads matching the rewritten expression with reversed operands of `==` when doing overload resolution.

---

> to an explicit value,

> explicit constant

I am not sure what you mean here, but "*explicit value*" and "*explicit constant*" are not standard terminology. Probably you mean "*(string) literal*" instead.

> and says, "hey, == makes no sense on char*"

It doesn't work that way. As soon as either side of `==` is a class type, the compiler has to consider that `==` may be overloaded to match the expression.

Comment: "As soon as either side of == is a class type, the compiler has to consider that == may be overloaded to match the expression."

Aha, I was under the mistaken impression that it was always the first (left-most) operand encountered that determined where to go looking for a definition.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the class template `std::basic_string` the equality operator `==` is overloaded in particular the following way

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const charT* lhs, const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs);
```

So the first argument maybe a C string literal without requiring any conversion (except the standard implicit conversion from an array type to pointer to the array element type).

Actually the operator has three overloads

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& lhs,
const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs) noexcept;

template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const charT* lhs, const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs);
```

and

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& lhs,
const charT* rhs);
```